# Can I use Recurly.js on a Squarespace site?

Tags: javascript, e-commerce, squarespace, recurly

I'm working on someone else's Squarespace site for them.

Here's the current setup:

- A standard Squarespace site
- They do NOT want to use Squarespace's built-in e-commerce functionality
- They set up a Recurly hosted page to accept payments

Here is their ask:

- They want to add Apple Pay to their checkout page. They can't add it to the Recurly hosted page because it doesn't support Apple Pay.
- So they asked me to build a new payments page using Recurly.js
- I created a new page on Squarespace and using a code block, I was able to talk to Recurly and get a token.
- However, after getting the token from Recurly, you are supposed to use the Recurly client library on the server side to create a secure API call

Where I am so far:

- It seems like you can't make a secure API call from Squarespace! Based on answers I found like [this one](https://forum.squarespace.com/topic/185806-in-squarespace-developer-mode-can-one-save-the-aws-cli-sdk-to-the-websites-server-side-%E2%80%9Chome%E2%80%9D-directory-if-so-how/)
- I found something called [Pipedream](https://pipedream.com/) that says it runs integrations between sites, and lists both Squarespace and Recurly, but I can't figure out what it actually does or how to actually use it (or if it will even solve my problem!)
- Perhaps there is some other software or product or something that will allow me to do this, but I don't know where to start looking!

I feel like the answer might be "this is impossible, Squarespace is only meant for using the built-in commerce options" but I just really need to be sure there's nothing I can do before I throw in the towel! Thanks!